# How to put a MessageBox to display my Fibonacci sequence vertically

Tags: c#

Here's my finished code, just need a little advice as to where and how to insert my desired MessageBox. It needs to display my finished sequence vertically, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
public static double Fibonacci(double n)
{
    double a = 0;
    double b = 1;

    for (double i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double sum = a;
        a = b;
        b = sum + b;
    }
    return a;


  }

static void Main()
{
    for (double i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Fibonacci(i));

    }


}
}
```

Comment: You need a different kind of application than Console Application. Either use WPF or WinForm which has MessageBox

Comment: what's wrong with just displaying it in the Console?  Put a Console.Read() after your loop and it won't automatically close.

Comment: Instead of outputting intermediate results with `Console.WriteLine` you'll have to combine them into single string, which then can be shown after loop with `MessageBox.Show`. `WriteLine` adds `\n` (0xD+0xA) at the end of line, in case of string (vertically huh?) you will have to add that manually after each result.

Comment: Your code already writes the numbers vertically. Don't you mean Horizontally? if yes change your code to `Console.Write(Fibonacci(i)+",");`

Comment: Vertically in a MessageBox, I know I'm better off doing it in a Windows Form App but I want to be able to do it in Console first

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to show a MessageBox, try:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<double> nums = new List<double>();
    for (double i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        nums.Add(Fibonacci(i));
    }

    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, nums));
}
```

A console application can display a MessageBox if you've included the right libraries, and it looks like you already include `System.Windows.Forms`, so you should be all set.

Although honestly, your method isn't very efficient, everytime you call it, it has to recalculate all the numbers up to the term you want.  I would use a `yield return`, then your `Main` can be a one liner:

```
class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<long> Fibonacci(int n)
    {
        long a = 0;
        long b = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            yield return a;

            long sum = a;
            a = b;
            b = sum + b;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, Fibonacci(12)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your code as it is already displays the sequence vertically.

I assume you mean horizontally, in which case you could do something like this:

```
var fibonaccis = Enumerable.Range(0, 11) // generates the numbers 0 to 11
                   .Select(number => Fibonacci(number)); // fibonacci-ify

var output = String.Join(", ", fibonaccis);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: No, I meant vertically in a MessageBox, I know I'm better off using a Windows Form Application but I want to be able to do it in a Console App.

Comment: Why do you need to use a MessageBox? Is there any reason you can't just use the plain console?

Comment: Requirement for the output, was told I can't use a Windows Form App nor can I just leave it in Console. Yeah, I know...

Comment: `<joke>`Save the output as HTML and open it in a browser`</joke>` :P